# Video upload with iOS Facebook SDK 3.2.1 randomly stops

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I guess it's not specific to video uploads, since I'm just doing a post to the graph, but when I use the following code the upload sometimes stops. Smaller videos (<20MB) womewhat reliably go through, but larger videos (50 to 200 MB) are guaranteed to fail.

```
    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:video.localURL options:NSDataReadingMappedAlways error:&error];

NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               videoData, video.localURL,
                               @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                               video.name, @"title",
                               NSLocalizedString(@"Test http://www.apple.com", @"Facebook upload description"), @"description",
                               nil];


FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/videos" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"result: %@, error: %@", result, error);
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:FacbookUploadFinishedNotification object:nil];

}];
```

I have patched FBURLConnection to get notifications about the upload progress:

```
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite {

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:totalBytesWritten],
                              [NSNumber numberWithInt:totalBytesExpectedToWrite],
                             nil]
                            forKeys:
                            [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             @"bytes",
                              @"totalBytes",
                              nil]
    ];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:FacebookUploadProgressNotification
                                                        object:self
                                                      userInfo:userInfo];



}
```

To me it looks like the Facebook servers just stop responding… didSendBodyData stops getting called and the request times out after a while.

Uploading the same videos with the FB app works…

Edit: Ah, forgot to add that the Facebook app ID I'm using in this app is not yet submitted. Are the requests possibly going to some (less reliable) testing servers? Uploaded videos appear in my timeline though…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that Facebook only accepts longer videos at https://graph-video.facebook.com. The SDK does not consider this.

My app does not use all the fancy stuff contained in the 3.x SDK. I load the friends information and their images (that's all I need) with my own code. Perhaps my solution will not work when utilizing all the bells and whistles of the 3.x SDK.

Here's what I did:

Remove all references to the previously installed SDK from your project, including search paths and frameworks. Add Accounts.framework, AdSupport.framework, Social.framework and libsqlite3.0.dylib if you haven't done so already.

Download the source of the SDK from GitHub. Within the .zip file you will find a folder "src". Create a folder in your project directory. Name it "facebook-ios-sdk" or whatever you like. Copy the contents of the "src" folder including the subfolder "JSON" to the newly created folder.

Drag the folder to your Xcode project. Remove the contained Xcode project and precompiled header. After that, your project should compile fine again. Videos won't upload.

Open `FBRequestConnection.m`

In the first line after all the #imports add `BOOL bGraphIsVideo = NO;`

Some lines below you will find a line reading
`NSString *const kGraphBaseURL`....
Add the following line:
`NSString *const kGraphBaseURLVideo = @"https://graph-video." FB_BASE_URL @"/";`

Then find the method `urlStringForSingleRequest`

Change the line reading

```
baseURL = [kGraphBaseURL stringByAppendingString:request.graphPath];
```

to

```
if (bGraphIsVideo)
    baseURL = [kGraphBaseURLVideo stringByAppendingString:request.graphPath];
else
    baseURL = [kGraphBaseURL stringByAppendingString:request.graphPath];
```

Add the following static method in the .m file

```
+ (void)setVideoMode:(BOOL)videoMode {
    bGraphIsVideo = videoMode;
}
```

…and in the .h file

```
+ (void)setVideoMode:(BOOL)videoMode;
```

Now update your code to post a video file:

```
    [FBRequestConnection setVideoMode:YES];
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:<Your path>
                                 parameters:<Your params>
                                 HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                              [FBRequestConnection setVideoMode:NO];

                              if(!error) {
                                  NSLog(@"OK: %@", result);
                              } else
                                  NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);

                          }];
```

This works like a charm for me. Please forgive the horrible formatting of this text. It's my first one.

This is definitely a hack. I do not want to discuss on how to make it better. I just want to upload a video file to Facebook, not more, not less. And because I see people are in trouble with it, I want to share my way of doing it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm not sure if i would have ever figured this out by myself! :) What a great first post!

Comment: Really great way to get around it, have you thought about forking the SDK and doing a pull request on this to them?

Comment: I think this is implemented in the sdk i'm trying now, 3.10. However is crashing at some point and the memory is not going up so much

Comment: It's nice that SDK 3.13.1 detects 'me/videos' call and replaces the url to 'graph-video.facebook.com'